# How to access or redirect uploaded images

Tags: laravel-5

I'm new to `laravel 5.7`, i have uploaded my first project to shared hosting, i put all my project to ftp /domain/app... and public folder i copied /domain/public_html everything works fine, problem is that database stores everything in domain/app/public/uploads/avatars i either access it by `<img src="url"` somehow, or change the folder so it uploads everything domain/public_html/uploads/avatars any ideas? tried to change links I dont know what to do looking at it for past 8 hours =/

Answer (score 0):

I made syslink using SSH, It was hard to enable it though, but hostinger support was happy to help with it 
i used `ln -s /home/user/domains/domain/app/public/uploads/ /home/user/domains/domain/public_html`.